# Optimal algorithm for covering all non-ordered 3-tuples in a set of N, using M-tuples (M<N)

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a set of N items, of which I need to cover all 3-tuples.
I can do this using M-tuples, and it's important that I use a minimal number of M-tuples, because for each one I need to make an expensive API call.

For example:

```
N = 5, M=4
Set = {1,2,3,4,5}
A minimal set of non-ordered 4-tuples will be:
{{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,5},{1,3,4,5}} - and it covers all possible 3-tuples from the set
```

Is there a known algorithm (or better yet a python library :)) that does it?

Comment: Could you explain clearer on what do you hope to achieve?

Comment: Like `itertools.combinations` does but without `{1, 2, 4, 5}`?

Comment: This looks like a slight relaxation of a "t-design", for t=3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Generalization:_t-designs

Comment: And in general it's a Set Cover problem.  Set Cover is NP-complete and also difficult to approximate, but the instance you have here has a very special structure, so there might be faster methods for it.

Comment: Here is a simple (but not necessarily very tight) lower bound: Each M-tuple can cover at most (M choose 3) new 3-tuples, so you need *at least* (N choose 3)/(M choose 3) M-tuples to cover all of them.

Comment: How big do you expect N and M to be? How do you want to trade programming time against solution quality?